# Hero Wars RPG - The Sudoku!

Tags: steganography, sudoku, humor

In the popular online action RPG game Hero Wars, the player has to solve some simple but fun puzzles to win loot such as weapons and cash – assuming the incessant ads I’ve seen on Facebook are all legit.
The left image shows 4 purple question marks embedded in a grid (a5/d4/e4/d1 in algebraic chess notation) with each question mark corresponding to a different action: (i) pull horizontal pin, (ii) pull diagonal pin (iii) pull vertical pin (iv) switch the hero with the wine cask. To make the puzzle more challenging you also have to solve the Sudoku shown on the right.

[image]

**Instructions:**

- One of the cells is missing an even digit. Which cell and why?
- Solve the Sudoku. **If there are multiple solutions then you have
  to choose wisely!**
- Next, superimpose the completed Sudoku onto the left image so
  that the four purple question marks contain 1-2-3-9 in some order.
  You can rotate and reflect the Sudoku if necessary. Taking the
  Fourier Transform is not allowed.
- The digits 1-2-3 mean “perform these steps in order” and 9
  means DO NOT TOUCH. If you have the correct permutation then the
  loot is yours!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The missing digit is

> In the top middle cell, because with that, the given numbers will spell "HERO WARS RPG" in braille. If that digit is even, then it must be a 2. With that, we can solve most of the sudoku.
>  [image]
>  Now, since we want the steps in the left image to have the lava pin correspond to the 9, and the arrows be released after the switch with the wine cask, there's only one way to find such a solution to the sudoku.
>  [image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the given numbers will spell "HERO WARS RPG" in braille"?

Comment: Ignore the 3x3 boxes in the Sudoku and the empty ninth column and pretend the grid is divided into smaller boxes with 2 columns instead of 3.